# Ruby undefined method `binwrite' for IO:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, file, io, nomethoderror

Lately I get a very strange error at the following line of code:

```
IO.binwrite(attachmentUploadFile, attachmentFileContent)
```

This is the full error message:

```
import.rb:326:in `block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method `binwrite' for IO:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/juuro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/zippy-0.2.1/lib/zippy.rb:144:in `open'
from import.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from import.rb:320:in `each'
from import.rb:320:in `block in <main>'
from import.rb:167:in `each'
from import.rb:167:in `<main>'
```

It worked perfectly before. I haven't changed anything in my configuration. [I know there IS](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) a method 'binwrite' for IO:Class.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `ruby -v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your Ruby interpreter in your environment has is not the version which you expect.

You've linked to 1.9.3 documentation that supports the binwrite() method, but if I look at the path in your error message, I see a 1.9.2 version, and it doesn't look like 1.9.2 supports [that method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) from what I can see.  Maybe ask your Ruby interpreter what version it is and upgrade if necessary?

Comment: Thanks I updated to Ruby 1.9.3. Now it works (again). I think it had something todo with the update to OS X Mountain Lion. Although I'm sure that it worked already with Mountain Lion installed.